# Creating a categorical bar chart from csv file in c3.js

Tags: javascript, html, csv, c3.js

I have code for a simple bar chart using c3.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>C3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script>

        var chart = c3.generate({
            data: {
                url: 'data/output.csv'
                type: 'bar'
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The file `output.csv` looks like this:

```
A,B,C,D
25,50,75,100
```

And the graph ends up looking like this:

[image]

which is all of the data in one group.

**What I'd want to do is producing the following, without hard coding the data, but rather, getting it from the CSV file like the first example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>C3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>

        var chart = c3.generate({
                  bar: {
                      width: 15
                  },
                  padding: {
                      left: 60
                  },
                  data: {
                      x: 'Letter',
                      columns:
                          [
                        ['Letter', 'A','B','C','D'],
                        ['value', 25,50,75,100]
                        ],

                      type: 'bar',
                      onclick: function(e) { console.log(ylist[e.x]);a = this;}

                  },
                  axis: {
                      x: {
                          type: 'category'
                      }
                  },
                  legend: {
                      show: false
                  }
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

which would give a graph that looks like this:

[image]

Here is a [jFiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/bm57gye5/)

My main issue is not knowing if there is a way to split the CSV file into categories, since it seems like c3.js will always put a CSV file into a time series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C3 uses the first line in your csv as a header line and then returns a set of objects like {A:25},{B:50} which C3 will find difficult/impossible to use in the way you'd like.

Instead parse the csv outside the chart using D3's parseRows function. Then prepend a row descriptor which C3 can use to know which bit of the file does what.

https://jsfiddle.net/bm57gye5/2/

```
// This is a separate bit of html which is explained below
<pre id="data">
A,B,C,D
25,50,75,100
</pre>

// Actual javascript
var unparsedData = d3.select("pre#data").text();
var data = d3.csv.parseRows( unparsedData );
data[0].splice (0,0,"Letter");
data[1].splice (0,0,"Data");
console.log ("data", data);

var chart = c3.generate({
  bar: {
    width: 15
  },
  padding: {
    left: 60
  },
  data: {
    columns: data,
        x: "Letter",
    type: 'bar',
    onclick: function(e) { console.log(ylist[e.x]);a = this;}

  },
  axis: {
      x: {
          type: 'category'
       }
   },
  legend: {
    show: false
  }
});
```

To access the csv from a url (in the jsfiddle I just reference the data as part of the html) to feed into csv.parseRows you'll need to use d3.text and a callback as so:

```
d3.text("data/output.csv", function(unparsedData)
  {
   var data = d3.csv.parseRows(unparsedData);
... parsing / c3 chart generation continues on here as above ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks; that worked great! Is there an easy change I could make if I wanted to orient the csv file by rows (so that I can add in more information that could be used to filter the graph)? So the rows of the csv file would be `A,2`, `B,50`, `C,75`, `D,100`, with the possibility of adding more attributes, like: `A,25,YES`, `B,50,NO`, `C,75,YES`, `D,100,YES`.  If you think this should be in its own question, let me know, and I can do that.

Comment: You can make it row-based with that style of csv input with a couple of changes: `data.splice(0, 0, ["Letter", "Data"]);` and `rows: data,`. The trouble is any attributes you try to append to the rows C3 will try and draw. You'd have to pre-process your initial csv to produce a filtered csv to feed into the chart in your case.

Comment: I see. So assuming that I leave the csv file oriented by columns as in the original, if I add additional attributes on new rows, the rows of the csv file might looks like: `A,B,C`, `25,50,75`, `YES,NO,YES`.  If I then wanted to filter out the data that would be graphed (say for example, I wanted to graph only the data that had the third attribute as "YES"), then would there be a simple modification I could make to the `data[1].splice (0,0,"Data")` line to do so?

Comment: It'd be easier using the row-based csv approach and then filtering the parsed csv array to discard any row with a NO value, just using a normal array.filter(). However the surviving rows would still carry YES values through to C3. You'd need to hide those values in C3 using the data.hide facility http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-hide i.e. `hide: ["include"]` if you originally named the field that carried the NO/YES values as 'include'